# Как через PHP добавить дату в базу MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток. Как через PHP добавить дату в базу MySQL?.

Я перечитал десятки статей в гугле и на этом сайте, но ничего не помогло.

Если я пишу `date('Y-m-d');` - дату добавляет.

Если пишу `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` - ни дату, ни время не добавляет.

Все пишут, что с `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` у всех все работает, но у меня нет, не понимаю почему.

Да, я мог бы создать таблицу в БД (`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) и не парился бы, но мне это не подходит, так как после передачи даты у меня идет проверка на дубликат `on duplicate key update`, если такая запись уже есть, то просто нужно обновить дату и все.

Заранее благодарен всем за помощь.

Comment: `insert into table(...) values(...,now()) on duplicate key update set dt=now()`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поменять в таблице тип поля с `date` на `datetime`.

Comment: Тогда уж timestamp, колонки с таким типом автоматически обновляются на текущую дату при любой операции insert/update

Comment: я могу поменять на timestamp и тогда мне не придется делать INSERT с датой, но как мне в таком случае сделать on duplicate key update ?

Comment: @ВладимирВ. А в update любое поле само не себя поменяйте и все, а дату он сам изменит. но так же вы можете ничего не менять и писать запрос как я вам предложил в комментариях к вопросу. функция now() в MySQL дает текущую дату-время